# Does Go change the execution order of two mutex locks in a single goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency, compiler-optimization

If I have two resources that are protected by mutex, to avoid deadlock, I should lock them in a certain order. Go does not have a volatile keyword. So will the compiler change the execution order between these two lock operations?

Comment: the absense of a keyword does not imply the absense of functionality

Comment: If they have a defines execution order  this order won't be changed and if the execution order is not defined it  is not  defined.

Comment: This is like saying "Since there's no native English word for 'Sushi', does that mean Americans can't eat raw fish?"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Go memory model:

https://golang.org/ref/mem

In particular: mutexes can be used to establish a happened before relationship. If you lock one mutex before the other, all goroutines will observe those operations in that order.